# jQuery detect day of week to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jQuery script that would detect the day of the week, and display the associated ID.

I was wondering, how can I achieve the same thing in PHP?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { 
    today=new Date() 
    thisDay=today.getDay()

    $("#mon").hide();
    $("#tue").hide();
    $("#wed").hide();
    $("#thu").hide();
    $("#fri").hide();
    $("#sat").hide();

    if (thisDay == 1){ $("#mon").show(); }
    if (thisDay == 2){ $("#tue").show(); }
    if (thisDay == 3){ $("#wed").show(); }
    if (thisDay == 4){ $("#thu").show(); }
    if (thisDay == 5){ $("#fri").show(); }
    if (thisDay == 6){ $("#sat").show(); }
}); </script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't hide and show the div's in PHP if you mean you want to be able to do that on the fly in the browser without a page reload. What you can do is either only output the div you are interested or output all divs and make the 6 divs you do not want to show hidden via CSS (with PHP output appropriate class or style definition to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrote this to me more clear, got a little wordy before. You can use an array with the ids you are using along with `date('w')` to write styles that will hide or show a div depending on which day it is.

opening markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
```

Now create your array and write some styles based on what day it is.

```
$days = array('sun','mon','tue','wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat' );

foreach($days as $index=>$dayId){
   $display = $index == date('w') ? 'block' : 'none'; 
   echo '#'.$dayId.'{display:'.$display.';}';  
}
```

now close the style tag and begin the rest of the document.

```
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

I used `date('w')` instead of N as it starts at 0 and makes it easier to work with an array.

One more thing to add, make sure your [timezone is set correctly](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or you could experience some undesired results.

Comment: Um, dude...I need the same functionality, but in PHP. Trying to avoid jQuery for this specific matter.

Comment: That is php.... wrap that middle block of code in a `<?php` and closing `?>` tag and watch it go!

Comment: Yeah. But it has JavaScript in it. Can it be done completely with PHP or I'll have to use jQuery for the hiding and showing of the IDs?

Comment: That is completely PHP, it's echoing css not jquery.There isn't a single line of javascript in there

Comment: Thank you Bryan! Works like a charm! About the timezone, is `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');` correct? I just paste it in above the code you provided?

Comment: Depends on your timezone. But the date is calculated from whichever timezone you have set.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
  <?php 
        $week_day_as_number = date("N"); //e.g. 6
```

So the weekday is a number from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)

or you can do this:

```
  <?php
       $week_day_as_string = date("l"); //e.g. Saturday
```

So the result will be from: Monday - Sunday

Comment: You can simply to something like this: echo <div id="<?php echo $week_day_as_string ;?>"></div> .

Comment: So I have to do  `<?php $week_day_as_string = date("l"); $week_day_as_string = date("2"); $week_day_as_string = date("3"); $week_day_as_string = date("4"); $week_day_as_string = date("5"); $week_day_as_string = date("6"); ?>` for Mon to Sat. And then use `<?php echo $week_day_as_string ;?>` as an ID?